Beyond the $agm(1,x)$ ; $f(a,b) = f((a+b)/2,((a^{1/3} + b^{1/3})/2)^3) $
The Arithmetic-GeometricMean (agm) can be expressed by the CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.
$$agm(a,b) = agm((a+b)/2,\sqrt {ab})$$
$$agm(a,b) = \frac{(a+b)\pi}{4 K(\frac{a-b}{a+b})}$$
where K is the CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

to do the inverse of agm(1,x) see this here How to calculate the inverse agm(1,x)? )
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{2x_n(1+x_n)(agm(1,x_n)-y)}{agm(1,x_n)(1+x_n)(1-\frac{4}{(1+x_n)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{k-1}c_k^2)-x_n}$$ and $c_k^2=a_{k+1}^2-b_{k+1}^2$ using the AGM iteration, $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $x_n=agm^{-1}(y)$. For $x_0$ use $\frac{\pi}{2\ln(\frac{4}{x})}$ for $0<y<1$ and for larger values use $2x$ as $x_0$. Its also convergent for complex numbers.

$$c *agm(a,b) = agm(c a,c b)$$
and other equations might be usefull too.
and many integrals are known for it.
Notice the sqrt requires both $a,b$ to be positive, unless you want complex numbers as mean of reals ?
But I was thinking about the analogue :
$$f(a,b) = f((a+b)/2,((a^{1/3} + b^{1/3})/2)^3) $$
( notice for large $a,b$ we have $agm(a,b) < f(a,b) < (a+b)/2$ )
Can $f(a,b)$ be given by an integral ?
What equations does it satisfy ? Does it give closed form values ?
How to do the inverse ?
Basically, what is known about it ?
And what exactly does this minimize ?
( the ordinary mean minimizes sum_i $(x - x_i)^2$ for instance )
Main questions :
Can $f(a,b)$ be given by an integral ?
Is there a closed form for $f(1,2) = 1.47128005...$ ?
